# Multiple return statements

Tags: c++

I am currently reading "A tour of C++" from Bjarne Stroustup, and I saw the following example:

```
bool accept()
{
     cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";     // write question
     char answer = 0;                                  // initialize to a value that will not appear on input
     cin >> answer;                                    // read answer

     if (answer == 'y')
           return true;
     return false;
}
```

I thought using multiple return statements wasn't recommended. Wouldn't it be better practice in this case to create a bool variable, initialize it to 0 and then modify it in the if condition, to finally return the value of this boolean variable? Or I am just making things up.

Comment: Both is possible. With your second a bool variable - you need more memory to store this value. That's it. I have a third option: `return ( answer == 'y' ? true : false );` - With this you save 2 lines of code. ^^

Comment: "wasn't recommended" By whom? I don't know about any modern C++ style guide that recommends this. It could have been a thing when "structured programming" was a novel idea. Anyway, the example doesn't need any boolean variables. You could write a single return statement `return answer == 'y';`.

Comment: The suggestion that multiple returns are somehow “bad” may well be the result of a misinterpretation, see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793 If multiple returns (or any other commonly advised-against practice, like gotos, etc.) make the code clearer, then that should probably outweigh any concerns that the practice is somehow “bad”.

Comment: @Elliott, yeah it is possible too. I think not enough. I wrote to much code and my readabillity is so easier, I think.

Comment: Eschewing multiple returns is a concept that is part of **structured programming** movement of the late 1950s and 1960s. There were some languages that disallowed multiple return statements; and programming **flow charts** (not nearly as popular today as they were many decades ago) reinforce the notion.  Even today, some professors espouse the notion as a better or more proper way to program even in languages like C++ which don't enforce the single point of return. IMO, if your C++ routines are reasonable sized, multiple returns are okay. If they are 1000+ lines long, consider refactoring.

Comment: @Elliott, if you have your answer, kindly accept it as accept.

Comment: It dates from the concept that every block should have one entry and one exit. Structured Programming fanatics erected this into a religion that claimed it was better to litter your code with extra Booleans than to violate this sacred principle. You still find it occasionally in academia. In the real world, nobody cares.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you're not entirely making things up, and no there is no recommendation of such that I know of.

Snippet According to your recommendation:

```
Int accept()
{
     Int result=0;
     cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";     // write question
     char answer = 0;                                  // initialize to a value that will not appear on input
     cin >> answer;                                    // read answer

     if (answer != 'y')
         result=1;

     return result;
}
```

Looking closer you will notice no difference between the snippet above and the one you found in the book, they book use validation, the difference is the data-type used.
Now, it will be more easy to use a boolean if you need to simple use the function accept like below:

```
if(accept()) /*do something*/;
```

Rather than:

```
if(accept()==0) /*do something*/
```

Either way, you're good to go.

Another thing to consider is the size of your data-type, boolean is just 1bit while int is 4bytes so comparison time complexity will obviously be different but you will most likely never notice the difference.

Edit:

In java boolean is 1bit as said above but since it's c++, because of the issue of 1bit not addressable, it only make more sense to make it 8bit and then it can be given an address in the memory.
So, in C++ boolean is also 1byte or 8bit, and so the comparison time difference is not a thing to consider.

Comment: Isn't `bool` typically one byte? There are special libraries for bitwise booleans which is useful for long arrays where cache misses could be an issue. Also, not sure what any of this has to do with complexity? Whether you choose `bool` comparison or some `int`, it'll still be some constant time (maybe even the same time, depending on cpu's). I think the optimisation argument here is moot because the compiler will effect this code drastically.

Comment: No @Elliott the formula is 1bit= 1byte / 8

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with bits. However on c++ it's a full byte. This is to improve speed. Otherwise arrays of bits would require bit manipulation to access/edit, which would be slower than necessary.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Yes in C++ boolean is a full 8bit, this is because they needed it to be addressable since 1bit can't be addressable, it only make more sense to make it 8bit.

Comment: there used to be a thing with older standards and compilers where some [people] decided to say multiple returns are bad with the only solid justification being inability to constexpr (gone in newer standards), and lots of fishy justification saying multiple returns are more confusing than lots of deeply nested conditionals.  Personally I'm a fan of keeping relevant code together (conditions and resulting action) regardless of the number of return starements required to make it so. (Let confusion=total characters scrolled (vertically and horizontally) to trace every case.)

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are possible, but you will usually see the version using multiple return values. Take a look how this part of the code works:

```cpp
     if (answer == 'y')
           return true;
     return false;
```

At first you may see two branches in which the executed code can go, based on the value of `answer`. First one is connected with `y` choice, and the other one with anything else. This code could also look like this:

```cpp
     if (answer == 'y')
           return true;
     else
           return false;
```

But it makes the program a bit more complicated - there is one more `jmp` instruction in assembly code, which means that the code is just a bit more complex, but its functionality is exactly the same as of the previous version.

Now, we can add the `bool` variable and let's see how it will look like:

```cpp
     bool is_answer_positive = false;
     if (answer == 'y')
           is_answer_positive = true;
     else                              // we can get rid of this statement
           is_answer_positive = false; // as we have defined variable earlier

     return is_answer_positive;
```

The first thing which makes the code a bit more complex is a new variable, which does not add any vital value to the code, I would say it makes it only more complicated. This is the first instruction which makes the code bigger, but not better. Then `if/else` works similarly to the second version, but you also assign some values to the `is_answer_positive`, which also makes the code bigger, but not better. At the end, you return the value you got from `if/else` statement and the code is done. We can get rid of `else` statement, as `is_answer_positive` was initialized to be `false`, but this is still not the best solution.

Comparing those three possibilities: first version is the most used one, it is clear and probably the simplest, second version adds extra jump, which is unnecessary at all, and the third version adds extra variable, which makes the code a bit harder to read.

Comment: You don't need `else  is_answer_positive = false;` because your init it with `bool is_answer_positive = false;`